# VBA Selecting cells in a table based on a value and clearing contents

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Its been 2 days of failure so maybe someone here could help! I am trying to get my VBA to select values in my table that are "0" and clear the contents of that cell.

So far i have been able to get look up the table column i want to see

```
Sheets("formulas").Select 
Range("machine_schedule[days ]").Select
```

***if the days are 0 *** this is where i am having trouble

Then cell.Clear

Would love any suggestions! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `.select`. Try this...

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("formulas")
Set rng = ws.Range("machine_schedule[days ]")   'IDK about the space after days. could just use the days column/range.

For Each i In rng
    If i.Value = 0 Then
       i.Clear
    End If
Next i
```